# Expandable and collapsable TableView in JavaFX

Tags: java, swing, javafx-2

Using TableView or any other component, can we achieve the following functionality.

- Initially part of data in a table has to be shown with More button in the down.
- On click of more button UI should expand automatically by showing all the other data

Could someone suggest me about any readily available component or how can I achieve this functionality using JavaFX

Thanks in Advance
Viswanath

Comment: Probably [TreeTableView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/tree-table-view.htm)?

Comment: Hi Sergiy,  
Thanks for your comments. But using TreeTableView we would be able to expand and collapse each row but what I wanted is some part of the tree data has to be shown initially and the remaining part of data has to be show on click of the button.